# Rebuild link database is not working

Tags: link-database

I have installed Sitecore 9 update 1 in my local machine . When I try to rebuild the link database for the vanilla installation, the rebuilding keeps on processing and will never complete.

When I see the sitecore log file, there is below exception and nothing else.

```
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request. Source:
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web 

Nested Exception Exception : The certificate was not found. Source:
Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
```

Is rebuilding the link database related to xConnect ?

Is it mandatory to use xConnect in Sitecore 9?

How can I rebuild the link database without xConnect?

Comment: If you are not using xConnect, have you ensured the setting `Xdb.Enabled=false`?